# Difficulties converting date

Tags: php, date

Hi guys need a sort of help on java script  to display the date like this **310-201-22** but in my java script  it display like this **3102-01-22**

here is my code

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$date_enc = implode('-', array_map('strrev', explode('-', $date)));
```

i need to have an output like this   **310-201-22**

Comment: That's a valid date format?

Comment: What sort of date is `301-201-22`? I can't logically figure it out at all.

Comment: What part of your desired output is supposed to be what part of the actual date value?

Comment: Aaah - `310-201-22` is `22-10-2013` backwards with weird dashes!

Comment: FYI readers, `310-201-22` is a modification of `3102-01-22`, which is the reversal of today's date `22-10-2013`

Comment: Is there any logical reasoning behind the need of a format like this?

Comment: yes its a valid date format 3102-01-22
but i want to sort the date into 301-201-22 so that i'm the only one who knows the date format its like a secret identifier
@ben yes  exactly

Comment: If this is a form of security, I'd recommend something much more complex than reversing the string and changing the position of 2 characters, especially when the data is something as widely used as a date

Comment: what can you recommend  @smokeyphp

Comment: @Newbizone Let's start by asking you **why** you need to make this secret? If you read it with JS anyone can read the algorithm anyway.

Comment: @Newbizone The implementation and rest of project info would be useful - if this is auth, then server-side PHP auth would be preferable or at least HTTP auth with .htaccess - what's the main goal here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a string by it's character index:

```
String          | 2 | 0 | 1 | 3 | - | 1 | 0 | - | 2 | 2 |
                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
Character index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
```

Code:

```
<?php
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $date_enc = $date[3] . $date[2] . $date[1] . '-' . $date[0] . $date[6] . $date[5] . '-' . $date[9] . $date[8];
    var_dump($date_enc); //string(10) "310-201-22"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/3BEkGweT)

Comment: thank you so much love you you save my day !

Answer (score 1):

Using `substr` to get parts of the year, and reversing dates with `strrev`:

```
$year  = strrev(date("Y"));
$month = strrev(date("m"));
$day   = strrev(date("d"));

$yearpart1 = substr($year, 0, 3);
$yearpart2 = substr($year, 3, 4);

$date_enc = sprintf("%s-%s%s-%s", $yearpart1, $yearpart2, $month, $day);
```